# Cloudwatch alarm to monitor status check of all EC2 instances simultaneously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

How can we monitor the system status check of all EC2 instances simultaneously rather than setting up cloudwatch alarm at each EC2 level individually?

If it's not possible via cloudwatch service, can it be done using boto3?

Comment: That's a somewhat unusual request. What action do you plan to take on the alarm?

Comment: I want to be notified whenever any EC2 instance status checks fails. I do not want to set cloudwatch alarm at individual instance level. Hope it's clear now!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to setup alarms individually, you can automate it, whenever you boot new instance, you can setup cloudwatch rule(when instance state changes from pending to online) to trigger a lambda function, in lambda function you can setup cloudwatch alarm for that instance, for already existing instances also you can setup the alarm with little modification of that script.